# How to remove special character from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding

Hi I am trying to remove special character from csv file but not getting the satisfied result. Could you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
ÃÅ“ÃÂ¾Ã‘ÂÃÂºÃÂ²ÃÂ°
Ãâ€œÃÂ¾Ã‘â‚¬ÃÂ¾ÃÂ´ ÃÂ¡ÃÂ°ÃÂ½ÃÂºÃ‘â€š-ÃÅ¸ÃÂµÃ‘â€šÃÂµÃ‘â‚¬ÃÂ±Ã‘Æ’Ã‘â‚¬ÃÂ³
```

These king of special characters I am getting.

I am saving the file using below python code-

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Documents\cleanData-JnJv2.csv", low_memory=False)
df.to_csv(r"D:\Users\SPate233\Documents\cleanData-JnJv2_new.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Comment: You need to specify an encoding for the read_csv call. Do you know what encoding your input is written with?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try the `Code` Snippet given below:-

Basically, I have `DataFrame` from your `Data`. So, for Uploading `CSV` with **Special Characters**. It is important to specify the `encoding` type. So, I have used the `ISO-8859-1` type of `encoding` technique. Because `ISO-8859-1` is a family of single-byte encoding schemes used to represent alphabets that can be represented within the range of 127 to 255.

> To Learn more about `ISO-8859-1` [Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

```
# Import all the important Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Read 'Data'
df = pd.read_csv('temp_data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

# Print a few records of data with special characters
df
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    Data
0   ÃÅ“ÃÂ¾Ã‘ÂÃÂºÃÂ²ÃÂ°
1   Ãâ€œÃÂ¾Ã‘â‚¬ÃÂ¾ÃÂ´ ÃÂ¡ÃÂ°ÃÂ½ÃÂºÃ‘â€š-ÃÅ¸ÃÂµÃ‘â€šÃÂµÃ‘â‚¬ÃÂ±Ã‘Æ’Ã‘â‚¬ÃÂ³
```

After reading `DataFrame`. we can move towards, the process of removal of **Special Character**. `code` for the same was stated below:-

```
# Removal of Special Characters
df['Data'] = df['Data'].map(str).apply(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore'))

# Print Cleaned data
df
```

```
# Output of Above Cell:-
    Data
0   
1   -
```

As you can see we have removed all **Special Characters**. So, we can store this `Result`  to `CSV`:-

```
# Store clean data into 'CSV' Format
df.to_csv(r'cleaned_temp_data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index = False)
```

Hope this, Solution helps you.